# I want to add a UILabel from the outside to the collection view cell of my library

Tags: swift, frameworks

For the file PageCell0 in my library at github,
I want to use exetension in the project to introduce the library and add UILabel (newLabel) using addSubView.

I wrote it as follows at the place where I introduced the library, but I am troubled because the UILabel is not displayed in the simulator even if it is built.

I am looking for a solution but I do not know.

```
//Project file that introduced the library

import UIKit
import SlidingCellWithDrag0Framework

class ViewController: MainViewController {
    var cell1: PageCell1?

    var newLabel: UILabel = {
        let nL = UILabel()
        nL.textColor = UIColor.yellow
        nL.text = "newLabel"
　　　　　nL.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return nL
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        cell1?.addSubview(newLabel)

 　　　　newLabel.anchor(top: cell1?.topAnchor,
             leading: cell1?.leadingAnchor,
             bottom: nil,
             trailing: cell1?.trailingAnchor,
             padding: .init(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 30),
             size: .init(width: 300,
             height: 150))

    }
}
```

:Edit Code

````
// AppDelegate

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        
        let home = UINavigationController(rootViewController : ViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = home
    return true
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your newLabel.anchor function is an extension or not. But it looks like you’re adding the label and not using auto layout. As such you need to add `newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` So your label doesn’t use auto layout. This can be added either before or after you add the label as a sub view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco

Edit: Here’s a basic example with some of the padding code removed and the code slightly improved. I would set the cell value in your init. You’ll also need the init coder (on a mobile device so didn’t add it in).

```
import UIKit
import SlidingCellWithDrag0Framework

class ViewController: MainViewController {
    var cell1: PageCell1?

    var newLabel: UILabel = {
        let nL = UILabel()
        nL.textColor = UIColor.yellow
        nL.text = "newLabel"
        nL.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return nL
    }()

    init(cell1: PageCell1) {
        self.cell1 = cell1
    }

    // You'll need init coder here too

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        cell1.addSubview(newLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            newLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint.equalTo(cell1.leadingAnchor),
            newLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint.equalTo(cell1.trailingAnchor),
            newLabel.topAnchor.constraint.equalTo(cell1.topAnchor) // This is just a placeholder

            ])

    }
}
```

Comment: Added newLabel as an extension. I added newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false as in the text, but newLabel still does not appear.

Comment: Another issue I see is you’re setting a width and a height for the label explicitly and also using constraints that set your width (leading, trailing). Remove setting of the width and height and have the constraints do it.

Comment: Can not be displayed.

Originally, the UIView extension named Anchor I am using is set to translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. However, newLabel is not displayed even if this Anchor is used.
So I decided to stop using that Anchor and instead define newLbabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and set it in CGRect but the newLabel was not displayed as well.

Comment: Could you add some sample code in the way you mentioned? It seems that your method is correct, so can you show me the code?

Comment: Where are you initializing cell1? When creating the ViewController?

Comment: Your code generates an error and can not be resolved.
Check out the AppDelegate I added to the text and your code to the project from which you imported the framework.
I have at least two of the following errors:

Ambiguous reference to member 'constraint (equalToSystemSpacingAfter: multiplier :)'

・ Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ViewController' with no arguments

I get an error many times, and I'm really in trouble.

Sorry to trouble you, but can you push the project which imported my framework to github?

Comment: It can not be displayed in your way. Write the entire code, including constraints, in the response, not the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add subView directly to Cell. Do this instead:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(subView1)
```

Comment: It can not be displayed in your way.
Write the entire code, including constraints, in the response, not the snippet.